# Live video green screen effect (without green screen)

Tags: ios

I'm trying to figure this out for an iOS app I'm working on.  What I would like to do is basically mimic what the Photo Booth app does on the Mac.  When you click on Effects you are able to choose a background which is placed behind you by the app taking a picture of what you stand in front of and then when you step in the frame it will subtract what matches, leaving you visible, but not the background.  I'm not planning for it to be live streamed, but be able to make a recording with a different background behind me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called Chroma Key effect.

Here is a link to an article discussing it (which includes links to source code examples): http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1946398

And, a GitHub repo based on that article (which I don't think is linked): https://github.com/timsawtell/Greenscreen

Certainly good places to start.

Comment: I've looked into Chroma Key, but the problem is, I'm not using a solid background. I could be sitting in my office with a picture on the wall, or against wallpaper.  I want the user to step out of frame to allow the app to capture the background, so that when the background is changed to another picture, it will only show the difference between the picture it took and the camera, giving the green screen effect.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's a different task. I'd suggest looking at OpenCV.org (Open Source Computer Vision). Looks like lots of questions with OpenCV tag here on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opencv, as well as what appears to be an active IRC channel #opencv